# aws elasticbeanstalk terraform plan does not show sensitive setting

Tags: terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am using terraform to provision elasticbeanstalk and there have been no changes in my template but still when I try to plan, it shows me below:

```
  # module.abc.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.this will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "this" {
        id                     = "abc"
        name                   = "abc"
        tags                   = {}
        # (19 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ setting {
          # At least one attribute in this block is (or was) sensitive,
          # so its contents will not be displayed.
        }
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 3 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

I do not want to apply until I know what setting change it is referring to. Can someone help me show that setting output in tf plan output?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the configuration changes from AWS EB console - Change History